# Does there exist a continuous function $f$ such that $f(x)+f(x^2)=x$ for $x\in[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, power-series, examples-counterexamples, functional-equations

> Let $f$ be a continuous real valued function from $[0,1]$ such that 
>   $$f(x)+f(x^2)=x$$
>   for all $x\in [0,1]$. Does there exist such a function?

Plugging $x=0$ and $x=1$ respectively in the given equation we obtain $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}$. By the intermediate value theorem, $f$ attains any value between $0$ and $1$. Moreover, the range of $f$ is $[m,M]$ where $m$ (resp. $M$) is the minimum (resp. maximum) value of the function over $[0,1]$. How to use these facts to decide whether such function exists or not? Please give some hint to proceed. Thank you.

Comment: On $[0,1)$ it is easy, take $f(x)=\sum_{n \geq 0}{x^{2^{2n}}-x^{2^{2n+1}}}$. I’m not sure if the function extends by continuity to $1/2$ when $x \rightarrow 1$.

Comment: Ah, yes. "easy".

Comment: @Owen what is your idea? Does the function exist?

Comment: I'm not sure. My intuition says no, but I have not yet found a convincing argument as to why. In my previous comment I was trying to point out that the function suggested by Mindlack is not "easy" to find.

Comment: You are right. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this enough for a full answer but I tried showing that $f(x)$ must be the power series 

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n}x^{2^{n}}$$

which only converges for $x\in (0,1)$. This seems like it could lead to a contradiction somehow.

Comment: That expression is the same as Mindlack's. I guess you justify it by saying the sequence
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{1}&=&f(x^{2})=x-f(x),\\
f_{2}&=&f(x^{4})=x^{2}-x+f(x),\\
f_{3}&=&f(x^{8})=x^{4}-x^{2}+x-f(x)\quad\text{etc.}
\end{eqnarray*}
must converge to $0$.

But note also that on the other side the sequence
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_{-1}&=&f(x^{1/2})=x^{1/2}-f(x),\\
f_{-2}&=&f(x^{1/4})=x^{1/4}-x^{1/2}+f(x),\\
f_{-3}&=&f(x^{1/8})=x^{1/8}-x^{1/4}+x^{1/2}-f(x) \quad\text{etc.}
\end{eqnarray*}
must converge to $1/2$.

Comment: See this thread in MathOverflow. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198665/on-an-example-of-an-eventually-oscillating-function/307432#307432

Comment: @Sungjin Kim Thank you very much for the link you provided. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no such function. Suppose that $F(x)+F(x^2)=x$ and $F$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. We use the function $f(x), \ g(x)$ in my answer to [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198665/on-an-example-of-an-eventually-oscillating-function/307432#307432) where it is proved that $f(x)-g(x)$ is not a constant function. The functions $f(x), \ g(x)$ originate from Hardy's 'Divergent Series'. To recall the definition,
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^{2^n},
$$
$$
g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\log x)^n}{(2^n+1)n!}.
$$
It is easy to check that $f(x)+f(x^2)=x$ and $g(x)+g(x^2)=x$.

Now, since $F(x)$ on $[0,1]$ is continuous and $F(x)+F(x^2)=x$, we have $\Phi(x)=F(x)-g(x)$ satisfying
$$
\Phi(x)=-\Phi(x^2)=\Phi(x^4).
$$
Note that $g(x)$ is continuous on $(0,1]$. Thus, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1-} \Phi(x)$ exists. Then such $\Phi$ satisfying $\Phi(x)=\Phi(x^4)$ must be a constant function. Let $\Phi(x)=c$. We have 
$$
F(x)-g(x)=c \ \ \textrm{ if } x\in (0,1]. \ \ (1)
$$
Similarly, let $\Psi(x)=f(x)-F(x)$. Then $\Psi(x)=\Psi(x^4)$. As $f$ is a power series at $0$, we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} f(x) = 0$.
Then we must have $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} \Psi(x)=-F(0)$. Such $\Psi$ satisfying $\Psi(x)=\Psi(x^4)$ must be a constant function. Thus, 
$$
f(x)-F(x)=-F(0) \ \ \textrm{ if } x\in [0,1). \ \ (2)
$$
Summing up (1) and (2), we have 
$$
f(x)-g(x)=c-F(0) \ \ \textrm{ if } x\in (0,1). 
$$
Therefore, we have a contradiction since $f(x)-g(x)$ cannot be constant on $(0,1)$ as proved in my MO answer.

**Remark** The phenomenon we are observing here is that $f$ is oscillatory around $1$, and $g$ is oscillatory around $0$.

Comment: If I am understanding your answer correctly, doesn't this show that there is no such **unique** function defined by the constraints, rather than there being no functions at all?

Comment: No, the proof works because, I obtain contradiction by assuming existence of any such $F$.

Comment: Ah, my bad. To make it more explicit, you have shown that no such function satisfying the functional equation can be continuous at both $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.