# Prove that there does not exist a continuous function $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that: $ f(x) + f(x^2) = x$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that there does not exist a continuous function $f : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that: $ f(x) + f(x^2) = x$

I know that this is an old problem :  [Does there exist a continuous function $f$ such that $f(x)+f(x^2)=x$ for $x\in[0,1]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547680/does-there-exist-a-continuous-function-f-such-that-fxfx2-x-for-x-in0)

This problem used to be in our Olympic team selection exam. but I think the above solution is quite technical. Is there any other approach?

Comment: Try to take a look [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2012670p14112827)

Comment: Thank you very much!